# reverse a queue using an empty queue

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I have a queue [3,2,1] and I want to reverse it using only enqueue and dequeue functions. My final queue should be [1,2,3].

I cannot declare any local variables. I only have 2 queues one is empty and the other has data in it. I want to reverse the queue which has data using the empty queue only. I don't have access to the pointers of the queue.

I only have 1 global variable, but I can't declare local variables otherwise it can be done easily by recursion. And I don't have peek back and pop back function either. Only have enqueue, dequeue, length, empty and front.

Is this possible?

```
queue1 = [3,2,1]
queue2 = []

final result
queue1 = [1,2,3]
queue2 = []
```

Comment: How is this related to C or C++? Seems like you are looking for a pure algorithm.

Comment: Are you sure no variables are allowed? This reminds me of my programming class 10 years ago, where the task was similar, but with stacks and the peek function was banned. It said to only use stacks. I found it impossible to solve it, but the solution used variables and the TA said, yes of course you can use variables.

Comment: Use peek back and pop back on queue 1, push front the peeked back values into queue2

Comment: I only have 1 global variable, but I can't declare local variables otherwise it can be done easily by recursion. And I don't have peek back and pop back function either. Only have enqueue, dequeue, length, empty and front. It seems like impossible.

Comment: Should it work for **any** queue, or only for a queue with length 3?

Comment: queue of any length

Comment: And that global variable can be an integer type?

Comment: yes, it's already declared and it's of integer type.

Comment: OK, you have provided several clarifications in comments that should be present in the question as they are crucial. Will you edit the question and add all of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems crucial you have one global variable to use. So let that be a number which can be used for looping.

The idea is to rotate `queue1` (dequeue + enqueue) until it has its (originally) last element first. Then this one can be transferred to `queue2`. Now `queue1` looks like it was originally, but without its last element. Repeat this procedure until it is empty.

This gives the desired result in queue2. As it was asked to get the result in queue1, we can first move all elements from queue1 into queue2, except the last one. And then we can apply the above described procedure on queue2 and make the transfer of the wanted element to queue1.

```
global i

reverse(queue1):
    queue2 = new Queue()
 
    repeat queue1.length-1 times:
        queue2.equeue(queue1.dequeue())
    repeat until queue2.empty():
        for i = queue2.length-1 downto 1:
            queue2.equeue(queue2.dequeue())
        queue1.enqueue(queue2.dequeue())
```

Here is an implementation in runnable JavaScript snippet (`push` = enqueue, `shift` = dequeue):

```js
let i; // One global variable
let queue1 = [];
let queue2 = [];
// Populate the first queue
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    queue1.push(i);
}
console.log(...queue1);
// Start of the reversal algorithm
// Move all but the last element to the other queue
while (queue1.length > 1) {
    queue2.push(queue1.shift());
}
while (queue2.length > 0) {
    // Rotate queue2 to bring last element at the front
    for (i = queue2.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
        queue2.push(queue2.shift());
    }
    // Move that front element to the first queue
    queue1.push(queue2.shift());
}
// End of the algorithm. Print the result
console.log(...queue1);
```